# Google Coud SQL Postgres Database kills process and enters recovery mode

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm seeing my client's Cloud SQL database go into recovery mode every day or two. All connections are rejected with the error:

Every time this is proceeded by log messages stating:

- `server process (PID 2883588) was terminated by signal 9: Killed`
- The SQL query is logged, always the same query
- `terminating any other active server processes`
- Then many: `terminating connection because of crash of another server process`
- At which point the database comes back in recovery mode for a few seconds, before continuing life as normal.

Why would Cloud SQL be terminating a query for me? I've run the query in question (on the same server) and it completes happily in under a millisecond. Could this be caused by transient server load?

Comment: Hi @AdamCharnock by your description, I thnk it will be necessary that someone check the instance of your client, for more information and analysis. I would recommend you to reach out to Google's 1:1 support [here](https://cloud.google.com/support) for this kind of help.